# Using Service in Angular Custom ErrorHandler

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, error-handling, angular-routing, sentry

I have implemented the following `ErrorHandler` in my project:

```js
export class RavenErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(err: any): void {
    Raven.captureException(err.originalError);
  }
}
```

I also provided it correctly in my `AppModule`. But I also want to use an AlertService and a Router to route the user to a generic error page after I log the error remotely as is done above.

How do I go about in injecting those services to the custom ErrorHandler?

If I just inject them into the constructor, the app never loads (stuck at `Loading...`) and nothing is displayed on the console at all!

**UPDATE**: I added @Injectable to `RavenErrorHandler` above, and now I'm getting the following error:

```html
[Error] Unhandled Promise rejection: (8) "Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef (\"[ERROR ->]\"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1" "; Zone:" "
<root>" "; Task:" "Promise.then" "; Value:" Error: Provider parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1 — compiler.es5.js:10921 parse — compiler.es5.js:10921 compile — compiler.es5.js:17394
  _compileModule — compiler.es5.js:25652 run — zone.js:141 (anonymous function) — zone.js:805 runTask — zone.js:181 drainMicroTaskQueue — zone.js:574 promiseReactionJob (anonymous function) (vendor.bundle.js:98814) onUnhandledError (polyfills.bundle.js:2613)
  handleUnhandledRejection (polyfills.bundle.js:2637) _loop_1 (polyfills.bundle.js:2628) microtaskDrainDone (polyfills.bundle.js:2632) drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.bundle.js:2565) promiseReactionJob [Error] Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Provider
  parse errors: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1 parse@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:64024:28 compile@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:70497:29 _compileModule@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:78755:80
  run@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2124:49 http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2788:60 runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2164:57 drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2557:42 promiseReactionJob@[native
  code] — zone.js:757 (anonymous function) (vendor.bundle.js:98814) onUnhandledError (polyfills.bundle.js:2615) handleUnhandledRejection (polyfills.bundle.js:2637) _loop_1 (polyfills.bundle.js:2628) microtaskDrainDone (polyfills.bundle.js:2632) drainMicroTaskQueue
  (polyfills.bundle.js:2565) promiseReactionJob
```

Comment: what happens if you just reference them in constructor? class `RavenErrorHandler { constructor(as: AlertService, r: Router)`?

Comment: I didn't try because I saw that the constructor is deprecated in angular.io documentation!

Comment: that can't be true, can you provide a link? try it, but don't forget to also register your `AlertService` as a provider

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html

Comment: Alright, will do, I may have mis-understood the docs.

Comment: Oh, it's just the *parameter* that has been deprecated, no?

Comment: yeah, it's not the `constructor` deprecated, it's the parameter

Comment: But no, that doesn't work actually. The app never loads, just stays on the "loading" part, without actually displaying any errors at all in the console.

Comment: what version of router do you use?

Comment: From `package.json`: `"@angular/router": "^4.1.3"`

Comment: how do you register that error handler?

Comment: From my `app.module.ts`: `providers: [AlertService, SpinnerService, {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: RavenErrorHandler}],`

Comment: so this is not router specific error handler, right? it's the application level error handler?

Comment: To be honest I do not understand the difference... all I needed was an app-wide custom error handling method, and I read in the angular docs that this was the way to do it!

Comment: I see, I got confused because router has its own error handler, see [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterModule-class.html#!#forRoot-anchor). so what error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any errors, that's the problem, the app just hangs at loading :(

Comment: It would be better if you got errors :) So do something to cause an error. And also provide us a minimal working example

Comment: ...ok, so I finally got it to produce an error!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't inject `Router` directly but you can use injector and get `Router` instance within `handlerError` methos.

Don't forget to add `@Injectable()` decorator to your custom handler

```
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private service: TestService, private zone: NgZone, private inj: Injector) {
    super();
  }

  handleError(err) {
    let router = this.inj.get(Router);
    debugger;
  }
}
```

Test it **[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/3UrLKO9bgdurYIAgwJou?p=preview)**

Don't read below :) It's internally logic

So my module factory, that is generated from our code, will look like:

```
AppModuleInjector.prototype.createInternal = function() {
  var self = this;
  self._CommonModule_0 = new jit_CommonModule27();
  self._TestService_1 = new jit_TestService28();
  self._ErrorHandler_2 = new jit_MyErrorHandler29(self._TestService_1,self.parent.get(jit_NgZone16),self);
```

Comment: hah, I tried with the constructor the first time, and it didn't work... I forgot the @Injectable thing

Comment: Strange, I'm still getting `Unhandled promise rejection`

Comment: Oh, I think it worked; you must remove `private service: TestService` from the constructor though!

Comment: just in my example i use TestService